# Can you run Unity for Ubuntu in Docker as an alternate to VirtualBox?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, virtualbox

I currently use VirtualBox to virtualize my hardware. But, I have a relatively old computer with a Intel i5-3317u@1.7GHz processor with 4 cores. Two of those are dedicated to the base operating system, and two are dedicated to the virtual box.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 in the virtual environment and the programs I'm running are a little slower than I'd like.
I dedicated 8GB of ram to the whole box. I run on a typical hard disk, not an SSD.
I realize I may need to upgrade, but I don't want to spend the money right now.

I recently heard about docker and how light weight it is.
I was wondering if anyone has run Unity for the graphical component of Ubuntu with docker (and attached volumes) as an alternate to a VM?
And if they have had any noticeable performance benefit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using VirtualBox to run Ubuntu, that means your host OS (the "base operating system") is not Ubuntu or other Linux distro.

In which case (Windows or Mac)... you would end up using VirtualBox (or a [native Hypervisor like HyperV or HyperKit](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/)) anyway in order to run docker! That would not bring much improvement to your current setup.

Comment: Let's say I'm running Ubuntu as the host OS and just want to virtualize would KVM be better than docker? would docker be more lightweight? Does docker for windows avoid any of the hyperV pitfalls, i realize it runs on hyperv?

Comment: @fritz No, if you are using Ubuntu as the host OS, you do not virtualize anything: docker is directly accessible.

Comment: @fritz HyperV is a lightweight visualization solution. I prefer VirtualBox myself (to define more than one VM).